# how to display drop down on right side?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

I make a demo which work on desktop as well as mobile .My issue is when I check on desktop it work fine (my option display on header).but when i reduce the screen size move to mobile verson it not show a drop down which should display the menu option in dropdown here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyNLqa

```
#menubar li {
    display: inline;
    padding:0.5em;
    font-size:1.5em;
    color :red
}
#menubar li:last-child{
    color: black;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .large {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .small {
        display: none;
    }
}
#menubar{
    float:right;
    position:relative;
}

#menubarCont {
    width: 100%;
    right:5em;
    position:relative;
}
```

[image]

[image]
when I run my program it work it work fine but when I reduce screen It should display dropdown but it is not display why ?

I need dropdown show display on right side as shown in image ?

Comment: When I view your demo I am seeing the dropdown menu display after reducing screen size.  It appears to be working as you would expect.  Is their a particular device that you are not seeing the change?

Comment: I am check on browser..can on mac pro ..may be in i am using small screen that why it is not display ..can we shift to right ..as label in large screen can we use float right on dropdown ?

Comment: could you please shift to float right to dropdown so that it visible to all screens

Answer (score -1):

```
  #menubarCont {
        width: 100%;
        right:2em;
        position:relative;
    }
```